# Count all possible Tweets

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity

## Challenge

This challenge is pretty simple: Output the total number of possible Tweets. Given the fact that \$1{,}114{,}112\$ Unicode characters exist, and Tweets can be up to \$280\$ characters long, we calculate this number like so:

$$\sum_{l=1}^{280}1{,}114{,}112^l$$

Calculated, this number becomes:

```
13806352273767118967309446652268353719030666987497438863889357319392349204238070937934701588382252733861344864045882375396168022346806583217340072802259387083359555134466517197703380759356965846365156977627360473773588169473731316369188960207815543356617430699549282184606847903882093344681639583363887920162736670339584230464092411246928128751923029979554646202579157612845521194257627831816510188786486205364038342997992390163377307319320795770580125829871827813635107055402218833285288428245530361070090385299410480471800097379723938710176776857154693492888113262310774952935141264656128106489715644469204223123574077687056241600407855644698999923182052787491366956979702291906138690639325270704272468782453957210692358210530379637285511395582363214078004388847219660731573151720107026864311541883029164798133330444260768597550725802772979408391647537342929574104808498797769614795400908507365237326804077132929339660443550229992211585154931729238484097424201567163596712698594520366545693861474171972272416897768579601352059483077847068448856472837079895280084051348757113747847034093121500403990822456362331568718364029903237356710927604336216180583115812490741333484187646966386074557181286407949971654502112671681454373869734610539296783900783568039838348725239932066066987739369537132033298306852573056479318562759091086979441683964087623025801925326064609304055115943692782207092740008073169526779422072953119459819275895282587278291133892079932466034984180041060600579941010427931676118356402267755461169199685582252347150686196242972686980783271232177904787906691872492956841276422272710260778534487171700075108866361285159161816004238666402986057371469198754307817645454320666214400
```

## Rules

- You may output a float with only zeros after the decimal point.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Trailing whitespace is allowed.
- If possible, please link to an online interpreter (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run)) to run your program on.
- Please explain your answer. This is not necessary, but it makes it easier for others to understand.
- Languages newer than the question are allowed. This means you could create your own language where the empty program calculates this number, but don't expect any upvotes.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Brownie points for beating my [10 byte 05AB1E solution](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6N5zkz1MnY5tPbTFJ9f//38A "05AB1E – Try It Online").

Comment: Not that it matters for the challenge, but the number of tweets is a little less than that. Tweets consisting of only whitespace seem not to be allowed

Comment: @Luis Nice, didn't think of that. I *would* edit now... if only there weren't already 11 answers. :P It seems that the *real* number of possible Tweets would be \$\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{280}1,114,112^l-\sum_{l=1}^{280}25^l\$.

Comment: This number can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Makonede/05e6c3e9a3e9c956f7f8f60a5be75d17).

Comment: I've edited the Mathjax slightly; using commas in the thousands place unfortunately causes a noticeable gap between the "parts" of the integer, so I've removed it. Furthermore, using `\$\displaystyle\$` instead of `$$...$$` makes it look "off" when viewing on the app/mobile site (at least, it does for me)

Comment: You cannot use 280 characters and use the full Unicode range. [The 280 character limit is for non-CJK languages](https://blog.twitter.com/official/en_us/topics/product/2017/tweetingmadeeasier.html).

Comment: @Abigail Oh yeah, didn't know that. Upon some investigation it seems Twitter counts CJK characters as 2 characters. Try this yourself; paste 139 Chinese characters into a Tweet, and you'll see that you have two characters left in your Tweet.

Comment: Just curious, approximately what number is that in word form? I couldn’t get Wolfie to process it

Comment: @gen-ℤreadytoperish Approximately thirteen point eight tresexagintaquingentillion, if my calculations are correct.

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm giving away my 1337 Twitter secrets, but you can tweet all whitespace if you use the Combining Graphmeme Joiner between the first two characters. This is a valid tweet \u0020\u034F\u0020

Comment: @AndrewOgden The Combining Grapheme Joiner is not technically whitespace.

Comment: @Makonede it's literally an unprintable character, and the point is that that changes the calculation of the number of possible tweets.

Comment: @AndrewOgden As I said, it does not, since \$\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{280}25^l\$ is the number of tweets of only whitespace. CGJ is not included in those 25 characters, so it does not count. It is unprintable, but the total number of possible Tweets includes tweets containing unprintable characters. This means that many Tweets can look identical, but be different by, say, one unprintable character.

Comment: @Makonede I assumed that since it was modifying characters, it didn't count towards the 280 character total. I just tried it, and you're right.

Comment: And to think we're only on Unicode 13.0... https://www.unicode.org/versions/stats/chart_charbyyear.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
⁴‘æ«*Ɱ280S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//4oG04oCYw6bCqyrisa4yODBT//8)

-1 byte thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!

### How it works

```
⁴‘æ«*Ɱ280S - Main link. No arguments
⁴          - Yield 16 and set the argument to 16
 ‘         - Increment to 17
  æ«       - Implicitly using the left argument, bitshift left, yielding 1114112
      280  - Yield 280
     Ɱ     - Over each integer 1 ≤ i ≤ 280:
    *      -   Yield 1114112 to the power i
         S - Sum
```

Comment: [Alternate 11 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R45ZHDTMOLzu0GsjSerRxnZGFQfD//wA). Sadly just as long.

Comment: [Two](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//MjgxYjHhuIXigJzDkeG5oG/igJn//w) [more](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//MjgxYjHhuIXigJzDkeG5oG/igJn//w)

Comment: @UnrelatedString Those two are the same, and don't produce the correct output

Comment: @Arnauld Yep, but you can remove the second `⁴` as the `æ«` doesn't hook to the `*`, thanks!

Comment: I had a second one but got the same link twice! They do both produce the same wrong output, of course. Don't know how I didn't catch that...

Answer (score 54):

## [Emotion](https://github.com/Quantum64/Emotion), 17 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0//?state=JTdCJTIybW9kZSUyMiUzQSUyMmNvZGVwYWdlJTIyJTdE)

Explanation

```
 Push literal 280
 Enter an iteration block over the first stack value and push the iteration element register at the begining of each loop.
 Push literal 1
 Push the sum of the second and first stack values.
 Push literal 1114112
 Swap the top two stack values.
 Push the first stack value to the power of the second stack value.
 Push the sum of the second and first stack values.
 Ends a control flow structure.
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0//?state=JTdCJTIyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJDb2RlJTIyJTNBJTIyJUYwJTlGJTk4JThEJUYwJTlGJTk4JTgzJUYwJTlGJTkyJTgxJUYwJTlGJUE3JTlGJUYwJTlGJUE0JUFGJUYwJTlGJTk4JTgzJUYwJTlGJTk4JUE3JUYwJTlGJTk4JThEJUYwJTlGJTk4JTg0JUYwJTlGJUE0JUI2JUYwJTlGJTk5JTg2JUYwJTlGJTk5JTg2JUYwJTlGJTk4JUFDJUYwJTlGJThGJTgzJUYwJTlGJUE3JTlCJUYwJTlGJTk4JUE3JUYwJTlGJUE0JUEwJTIyJTJDJTIyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJBcmd1bWVudHMlMjIlM0ElMjIlMjIlMkMlMjJtb2RlJTIyJTNBJTIyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXIlMjIlN0Q=)

Comment: This is disgusting. I love it +1 :D

Comment: Perfect for twitter

Comment: afaik, this isn't 17 bytes, but 68 bytes: `echo -n "" | wc -c` give the right number i think. Still cool though.

Comment: @Nordine Lotfi It's 17 bytes. I have hyperlinked the codepage consisting of 256 emoji in my answer. Valid Emotion programs contain only those characters. Each emoji represents one byte.

Comment: But i thought one unicode char (at least most) consist of more than one byte? if not, how come program such as `xxd` or other hex editor show it as such? @Quantum64

Comment: @NordineLotfi [Unicode is one code page to rule them all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Relationship_to_Unicode). However Quantum 64's answer is using a [different code page](https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0//?state=JTdCJTIybW9kZSUyMiUzQSUyMmNvZGVwYWdlJTIyJTdE) where the required emojis only take up 1 byte. I'd suggest reading [Joel's post about Unicode and code pages](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: @NordineLotfi: Your console seems to be using UTF-8, in which the string is indeed 68 bytes (17 characters of 4 bytes each).  But Emotion uses its own character encoding that represents its emojis in a single byte (at the expense of being unable to represent any other characters).

Comment: I have been really impressed by 2 answers recently, one was a R answer and now this one

Answer (score 19):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 25 bytes

```hs
div(x^281-x)$x-1
x=8^5*34
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfaBvzPyWzTKMizsjCULdCU6VC15CrwtYizlTL2OR/bmJmnm1BUWZeiULi/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

### Why does it work?

1. \$8^5\cdot 34=1114112\$, but 1 byte shorter.
2. \$\sum_{l=1}^n x^l=\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1}\$.

---

## Boring answer, still 25 bytes

```hs
sum$map(1114112^)[1..280]
```

Comment: If anyone is curious about the mathematical proof for (2), look [here](https://u.davwheat.dev/Ew6p2B.png).

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 21 bytes

```
Tr[1114112^Range@280]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6Qo2tDQ0MTQ0CguKDEvPdXByMIg9n9AUWZeiYJD@v//AA)

-1 byte from @GregMartin

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @Level River St.*

Based on the formula presented in [@Delfad0r's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220930/88546).

```ruby
x=17<<16
p x**281/~-x-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8LW0NzGxtCMq0ChQkvLyMJQv063Qtfw/38A)

#### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

An interesting iterative solution. It uses the fact that `a + a*a + a*a*a...` is equal to `a*(1+a*(1+a*(1+...)))`.

```ruby
p eval'+1114112*x=1'*280
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhtSwxR13b0NDQxNDQSKvC1lBdy8jC4P9/AA)

Comment: For the 2nd answer, `x=34<<15` or `x=17<<16` is a byte shorter than `x=1114112`.

Comment: @Level River St Pretty neat! And it looks like to save a byte in many of the other answers here too.

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>183</s> <s>181</s> <s>167</s> <s>162</s> 161 bytes

*-1 byte ceilingcat*

```c
c;d;char s[1695],t[1695];x=281;y=1694;main(z){for(t[y-1]=1;--x;)for(z=y;z--;c/=10,d/=10)s[z]=(d+=s[z]+(t[z]=(c+=t[z]*17<<16)%10))%10;for(;y--;s[y]+=48);puts(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JUzLCsIwEPwVL0JiGnSl1sp2vyTkUDb4OPigqdBE/PaYxcu8mBm2F@ZSGAPydZxW0UF3Ovhm/jMutO8BE1XX4n28PVTWn/NzUrNLFjwBWrugliRTwmwt8pZg1wRBHV32pIIhEaaOxLIhERs4DgN0el17AignmOpDdMkbanuNr/ccVdT4LeUH)

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 33 bytes

```javascript
f=(n=280n)=>n&&1114112n**n--+f(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgEAXA28iuYbTSRz92lzCNQt5GRtffZq7t23p@zvsN0L2Y1URIcZnAaYVzIjKLRHiPEIZKYMuKrq2MTQ@qxGw/)

### 29 bytes

Porting [@Delfad0r's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220930/58563) saves 4 bytes:

```javascript
_=>((x=1114112n)**281n-x)/~-x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1k5Do8LW0NDQxNDQKE9TS8vIwjBPt0JTv0634n9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

Comment: `_=>(x=1114112n)**281n/~-x-1n`

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
16W17*X$280:^s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39As3NBcK0LFyMLAKq74/38A)

#### Explanation

```
16     % Push 16
W      % 2 raised to that
17     % Push 17
*      % Multiply. Gives 1114112
X$     % Convert to symbolic (to achieve arbitrary precision)
280    % Push 280
:      % Range. Gives [1 2 ... 280]
^      % Power, element-wise
s      % Sum. Implicit display
```

Comment: This seems to map directly to a 10-byter in 05AB1E (and the currently shortest known 05AB1E answer here is 10 bytes): `žH17*Ƶ´LmO` - `16W` → `žH`, `17*` → `17*`, `X$` → `‎`, `280` → `Ƶ´`, `:` → `L`, `^` → `m`, `s` → `O`

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 bytes

```
1#.1114112x^1+i.@280
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlbK4Qq2CgEA/ERkZGXEp66mkKtlYK6go6QBErINbVU3AO8nH7b6isZ2hoaGJoaFQRZ6idqedgZGHwX5MrNTkjXyFNXf0/AA)

Wasn't able to improve the straightforward answer.

Comment: Does using the equation (from the Haskell answer) instead of a sum help?

Comment: It did play around with it and wasn't able to make it help (even though you save on the numeric representation by 1 or 2 bytes you lose that or more in the rearrangement), but ofc that doesn't mean it's impossible...

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>38</s> 27 bytes

-11 bytes thanks to Bubbler!

```
1114112 280 [1,b] n^v sum .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXlJiXnloMYZelglQVKxSnFpam5iUDhQuKUktKKguKMvNKFKz/GxoamhgaGikYWRgoRBvqJMUq5MWVKRSX5iro/f8PAA)

Comment: [Using vector functions is much shorter.](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkqFXlJiXnloMYZelglQVKxSnFpam5iUDhQuKUktKKguKMvNKFKz/GxoamhgaGikYWRgoRBvqJMUq5MWVKRSX5iro/f8PAA)

Comment: @Bubbler Thank you! I always forget to use them...

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `sr`, 9 bytes

```
⁺∑ƛ»∆#∆»e
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=sr&code=%E2%81%BA%E2%88%91%C6%9B%C2%BB%E2%88%86%23%E2%88%86%C2%BBe&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
⁺∑        # push 280
  ƛ       # Map foreach (1...280)
   »∆#∆»  # Base-255 compressed 1112114
        e # Exponentiation
```

The `s` flag sums the ToS at the end of execution. The `r` flag reverses the order in which functions take their arguments, so you have \$ 1112114^n\$ instead of \$ n^{1112114} \$.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 9 bytes

```
»∆#∆»⁺∑ɾe
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C2%BB%E2%88%86%23%E2%88%86%C2%BB%E2%81%BA%E2%88%91%C9%BEe&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Thanks to Underslash for this

Comment: [10 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C2%BB%E2%88%86%23%E2%88%86%C2%BB280%C9%BEe&inputs=&header=&footer=) but it doesn't use -r.

Comment: @Underslash Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 19

```
B14112dd281^r-r1-/p
```

Uses @Delfad0r's sum trick.

Also in dc, `B` = 11, and `B14112` = 1114112.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/J0MTQ0CglxcjCMK5It8hQV7/g/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
•HYH•Ƶ´LmO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMij0gPIHls66EtPrn@//8DAA)

Likely Makonede's answer.

Thanks to [Kevin's tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/66833) on compressing integers in 05AB1E. Make sure you upvote it!

### How it works

```
•HYH•Ƶ´LmO - Program
•HYH•      - Compressed integer: 1114112
     Ƶ´    - Compressed integer: 280
       L   - Range [1, 2, ..., 280]
        m  - Raise 1114112 to the power of each
         O - Sum
```

Comment: That was one of the three solutions I found. Others: `ŽΓH5BƵ´LmO`, `ŽHH₁*Ƶ´LmO`

Comment: Another one: `žH17*Ƶ´LmO`

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes(?)

```
s^LhC\S280
```

[Try it here!](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5ELhC%5C%F4%8F%BF%BFS280&debug=0)

Pyth supposedly uses an SBCS, but I can't find any details about its actual codepage.

The reason I have my doubts about the byte count is that the code contains a character with codepoint 1114111, which certainly isn't normally represented in a single byte (and I VERY much doubt is in Pyth's code page). The code is 11 *characters* long, and Pyth reports the mystery character as taking 4 bytes. However, the interpreter reports a length of 12, and the number 1114111 takes 3 bytes. In short, 11, 12, 13, and 14 are all possible byte counts for this program.

I've chosen 14, as its the most likely (since, again, Pyth says the character is 4 bytes).

Comment: This should be 14 bytes as [according to Pyth](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=.H%5C%F4%8F%BF%BF&debug=0) the character you have used is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 27 bytes

```bash
seq -f1114112^%g -s+ 280|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEE3zdDQ0MTQ0ChONV1Bt1hbwcjCoCYp@f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, <s>47</s> 44 bytes

Corrected answer *and* saved 3 bytes thanks to @mik!

```
()=>{val x=17<<16:BigInt;x.pow(281)/(x-1)-1}
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YgsAVMggQoO5y99qhKXFKg)

Not particularly short, but it uses the simplification of the sum to avoid all the exponentiation + summation, unlike the other answers.

Comment: Your answer is 1 too big. Correct and shorter: `()=>{val x=17<<16:BigInt;x.pow(281)/(x-1)-1}`.

Comment: @mik Oops, didn't see that. And thanks for the golf!

Comment: @mik Welp, that was dumb. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), <s>59</s> 49 bytes

- 10 bytes thanks to mik!

```
procedure main();write(1114112^281/1114111-1);end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSE3MTNPQ9O6vCizJFXD0NDQxNDQKM7IwlAfwjbUNdS0Ts1L@f8fAA)

### Original solution, 59 bytes:

```
procedure main()
t:=0
t+:=1114112^(1to 280)&\z
write(t)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSE3MTNPQ5OrxMrWgKtE28rW0NDQxNDQKE7DsCRfwcjCQFMtpoqrvCizJFWjRJMrNS/l/38A)

Comment: Much shorter: `procedure main()
write(1114112^281/1114111-1)
end`

Comment: @mik Thanks! Yes, this approach in much shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 44 bytes

```powershell
1..280|%{$k+="[bigint]1114112*"*$_+1|iex};$k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz8jCoEa1WiVb21YpOikzPTOvJNbQ0NDE0NBIS0lLJV7bsCYztaLWWiX7/38A)

**-18 bytes thanks to @ZaelinGoodman**

## Powershell v7, 37 bytes, thanks to @mazzy

```powershell
1..280|%{$k+="1114112n*"*$_+1|iex};$k
```

Comment: You don't need to declare K; it will adopt whatever type is being added to it with += if it is not yet initialized. You also don't need to concatenate the type accelerator with the number, so you can do `"[bigint]1114112"*$...`. Finally, the addition operator uses the type of whatever is on the left hand, so you do not need to make `1` a string to concatenate it. those changes all together get you down to 44 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz8jCoEa1WiVb21YpOikzPTOvJNbQ0NDE0NBIS0lLJV7bsCYztaLWWiX7/38A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: with PS7 you can to use [n-suffix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7) also. `1..280|%{$k+="1114112n*"*$_+1|iex};$k`

Answer (score 2):

## Deadfish~, 8398 bytes

```
{i}dds{i}dsiis{{{i}i}iiii}iiiis{{{{{{ii}iiii}iiiii}iii}i}ddi}dds{{{{{{{{{{{{{i}ddi}di}ddi}dddi}ddi}d}i}iiii}i}ii}dddi}ddi}ds{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{i}dd}iiiiiii}d}i}iiiii}ii}}iiii}iiiiii}iiiiiii}d}iiiiii}iiii}iiiiii}i}ddd}iiiii}iiiii}}iiii}iii}iiiiii}iii}d}iii}iiiis{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{i}}ii}ddd}iiiiii}iii}ii}iiii}i}di}ddi}d}i}iiii}dd}iiiii}}iii}d}iiiiii}iii}d}ii}ii}i}dd}ii}i}i}iiii}}ii}d}iii}d}iiii}iiiiii}dd}iiii}d}iiiiii}d}iiiii}ii}ii}iiii}iiii}iiiii}i}i}}i}d}iiiiiis{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{iii}iiiii}dddi}dd}}i}ddd}ii}ii}iiiii}iii}iiiii}i}dddi}dddi}ddd}iiii}i}iiiii}iiiiii}iiii}iiii}ii}ii}ii}iii}iiii}ddi}dd}iiiiii}ii}iiiiii}iiiii}i}iiiiii}}iiiiii}}}iiiiii}iiiiii}d}iiiii}dd}}iiiiii}}iii}dddi}d}iiiii}i}iiiiii}i}d}ii}iiiii}iiii}iii}iiiii}iiiii}d}i}}}iiii}i}i}i}ddi}ddd}i}iiiiii}iiiii}ddd}iii}iiiii}iii}dddi}dd}iiiiii}ddi}ddd}ii}iiiiii}iiiiii}ddd}iiiii}iiiiiii}dd}iiiiii}iiii}iiiii}ddd}iii}dd}i}i}ddd}iiiiii}d}i}di}dd}i}iiis{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{i}dd}i}iii}d}iii}ddi}d}iii}d}iiiiii}iii}iiiii}ddd}iiii}dd}ii}iiii}}iiiiiii}ddd}iiii}iiiiii}i}iii}iiiiii}di}dd}iiiiii}d}iii}iii}iii}iiiiii}iiiiii}d}i}iiiiiii}dd}ii}iii}iiiii}ddi}ddi}d}i}iiii}iiiiii}iiii}iiii}iiiii}ii}ddd}i}iiiiii}ii}iiii}i}iiii}iii}iiiii}iii}di}d}ii}dddi}di}di}dd}iiiii}d}i}iiiiii}iiiii}di}d}}ii}ddi}ddi}ddd}ii}iii}d}i}iii}ddd}}iiiii}iiiiii}ii}}iiiiiii}d}iiii}iiiiii}iii}}iiii}dd}iiii}ddi}dddi}ddi}d}iii}iiii}iiii}ii}iiii}dd}i}}i}ddd}ii}ddd}ii}iiii}dd}iii}i}ii}iii}ii}ii}iiiii}iiiiii}}i}ii}ddd}}iiiii}d}iiiiiii}dddi}ddi}ddd}i}iiiii}iiiii}iiiiii}iii}ddd}}i}d}iiiii}iiiii}i}iii}d}i}iiiii}iiiiiii}d}iii}iii}di}dd}iiiii}iiiii}iii}iiii}dd}iiii}ddi}dd}ii}iiii}iii}iiiii}iiii}dddi}di}ddi}dddi}ddd}iiiiii}dd}ii}iiii}iiiiii}iiii}iiii}}ii}ddi}ddi}dddi}dddi}ddd}iiiiii}iiiiii}iiii}ii}dddi}dd}ii}dd}ii}iii}iiii}iiiiii}ddd}}iiii}ii}dddi}ddd}iii}is{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{iiiii}iiiiii}d}iiii}i}ddd}i}iiii}dd}iii}ddd}ii}i}ddi}dd}iiii}iiiii}iiiiii}ii}iiiii}iiiii}i}d}iiiii}iiii}iiiiii}}iiiii}iiiii}dd}iiii}iiiii}di}dd}iiiii}ddd}iii}di}dd}ii}iii}ii}iiii}iiiiii}}iiiiiii}ddd}}iii}}i}iiiiii}ddd}}iiiii}i}iiiiii}d}ii}ii}iii}dd}ii}iiiii}iiiii}iiiii}ii}iiii}iiiiii}iii}}iiiiii}iiiiii}}iiii}iiiii}iiiii}i}i}d}i}i}i}iiii}ddd}iiiii}iii}ii}iiii}iii}dd}iiiiii}iii}i}iiiii}dd}ii}dd}}ii}iii}ii}iiiiii}iiiiii}i}ii}ddi}d}}ii}i}iiiiii}iiii}iiiiiii}d}iiiii}iiiii}iii}i}dddi}dddi}ddd}iii}d}iiiii}dddi}d}iiiii}iii}ddi}ddi}d}ii}di}ddd}iiii}iiiii}i}dd}ii}iiii}iii}iiiii}ii}iii}dddi}dd}iiiiii}dd}iiii}iiii}ddd}iii}ii}ii}iii}iiiiii}ddd}}iii}iiiiiii}dddi}di}d}iiiiii}d}iii}ddd}ii}iii}}i}iiiiii}}ii}}i}iiii}iii}iiiii}ii}}iiii}iiiiii}i}}iii}iiiiii}}iiii}iii}iii}iiiiii}}iiiii}i}iiiiii}dd}iii}ddd}iii}iiiii}iiiii}iiiii}i}iiiiii}i}di}dddi}d}ii}iii}dd}iiiii}iiiii}iiii}ddd}iii}iii}i}ddi}dd}iiiii}}iii}i}iiii}ii}iii}iiiiiii}dd}iii}ii}i}d}iiiiii}dd}iiii}}iiiiii}d}}ii}iiiiii}i}dddi}ddd}iii}ddi}di}ddd}iii}}ii}iiiiii}ii}d}iiiiiii}d}iiii}iiiiiii}dd}ii}ddd}i}iiiiii}ii}ddd}iii}iiiiii}di}dd}iii}}iiii}ddd}}iiiii}d}iiii}iiiii}ddd}iiii}d}iii}d}iiiii}dddi}d}ii}ii}iiiiii}i}d}iiiii}di}ddd}ii}iiiii}iii}iii}iiii}iiiiii}iiiii}iiiii}iiiiiii}dd}iiii}iiiii}ii}iiiiii}i}iiiiii}dd}}iii}d}iiiiii}i}ii}ii}iiiii}iiii}ddd}}iiiiii}iiiii}iiiiii}ii}iiiiii}iiiii}iii}ii}ddi}ddi}dd}iiiii}i}}ii}iiiii}dd}i}ddi}di}d}ii}dddi}dd}}iiiii}iiii}iiiii}ddi}dd}iiiiii}iiiiii}i}iii}iiii}iiiiii}iiiiii}dd}i}ddd}i}i}di}ddd}ii}i}iiii}ddd}ii}iii}di}dd}ii}iiiiii}iiii}dd}iiii}ii}dd}iiii}d}}ii}di}d}iiiiii}}ii}ii}iiiiiii}di}di}dd}iiiii}iii}i}i}iiiii}d}}iii}iiiiii}iiiiii}iiii}i}d}iii}iii}d}iii}dd}ii}iiiii}di}ddd}}iii}ds{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{iii}iiiii}i}iiii}d}i}ddi}dd}ii}iiiiii}iiii}ddd}}ii}dddi}ddd}iii}iiii}dd}iiiiii}dd}iiiii}iiiii}ii}iiiii}iii}iiii}}iiiii}ii}i}ddd}iiiiii}iiii}iiiiii}iiiiii}iii}ii}iiiii}}iiii}iiiiiii}dd}iiiiiii}dddi}di}dddi}ddd}iiiiii}dddi}ddd}iii}ddd}iii}ddi}ddd}}iiiii}ii}ddd}iiii}iiiiii}ddd}iiiiiii}d}iiiii}iiiii}iii}i}iiiiii}}ii}ddd}iiii}iiiiiii}ddi}di}d}iii}iiii}iiiiii}dd}}i}ddd}iiiii}}}}iiiii}ddd}}i}iiii}dd}iii}iiiii}iiiii}}iiii}ddi}ddd}iii}iiiii}i}iiiii}ii}d}i}ii}iii}iiiiii}d}iiiii}d}iiii}ddd}ii}iiii}ii}}i}}iiiiii}iiiii}}iiiiii}dd}iiii}iiiii}iii}ii}ddi}d}iiiiiii}ddd}iiii}ddi}ddi}di}dd}iii}ii}iii}i}iiiiiii}di}ddd}}ii}ddi}di}d}iiiii}d}}ii}}ii}ii}ii}dd}iiiiii}i}iiiii}dddi}ddd}iii}i}iii}ddi}ddd}iiii}d}i}iiiiii}dd}iiiiiii}dddi}d}iiii}i}iiii}d}i}ii}iii}d}}ii}iii}i}iiiiiii}dddi}ddi}ddd}i}iiiii}iiii}i}iii}iiiii}}iiiiii}d}iiii}}iiiiii}dd}iiii}d}i}iiii}i}ii}iiiiii}i}i}iiiiiii}di}ddd}iiii}iii}}iiii}ddi}di}ddd}iiiii}iii}ddi}dd}iiiiii}iiii}iii}iiii}ddd}iiii}iii}iiiiii}iiii}iiii}d}iiiiiii}ddd}iii}iiii}ddi}di}dd}i}d}iiiiii}iiiii}iiiii}dd}iii}iiii}i}ii}ddd}}iiiiii}dddi}ddd}iii}iiii}iiiiiii}d}iiiii}iiiiii}iii}iii}iiiii}dd}iiiii}iiiii}iiiiii}i}dddi}ddd}iiiiiii}ddd}iiii}ii}i}iii}iii}iiii}iiiii}ii}ii}ii}ddd}ii}iiiiii}di}dd}iiii}dd}iiii}iiiii}iiiiii}iiiii}iiiii}ddi}d}iiii}iiii}ii}iii}i}iiiiii}iii}}i}iiiii}iiii}d}i}iiiiii}iiiii}dddi}dd}iii}iii}di}d}iii}iiiii}dd}i}ddd}iiiiii}iiii}dddi}ddd}}iii}iii}ii}i}ddi}ddd}ii}dd}i}}iiiiii}dd}}iiii}ii}dddi}ddd}i}iii}i}iiiii}ddd}ii}dd}iiii}}i}iiiiii}ii}}iiiiii}dddi}d}ii}ii}iiii}iiiiii}i}ddd}iiiiii}iiiiiii}dd}i}iiiiii}iii}iiiiii}iiii}ddd}iiii}iiiiii}dddi}ddd}iiii}iiii}ii}i}ii}iii}ii}iiiiii}d}iiiiiii}di}ddi}ddi}dddi}dddi}d}iii}dd}iiiiiii}di}dd}iiiiii}iiiii}ddi}di}dd}i}iiiii}iiiiii}}iiiii}d}ii}ii}d}iii}iiii}ddd}iiiiii}i}}i}di}di}d}ii}ddd}ii}iii}dd}iiiiii}iiiii}d}iiiiiii}d}iii}ii}d}ii}iiiii}dd}}iiii}iii}iiii}ddd}iiiiii}iiii}iiiii}iiiii}ii}ii}iiiii}i}ddd}iiiii}iii}ii}iiiii}iii}iiiii}}}iii}iiiiii}}ii}}iiiiii}dd}iiiiii}ii}ii}i}iiiii}di}ddd}iiii}d}iiiiiii}ddi}ddd}iii}ddd}iiiiiii}di}ddd}ii}ddd}iiii}dd}}iii}iiiii}dd}iii}}iiiii}dd}ii}iiiii}}ii}ddd}ii}dd}iiiii}ddd}iiii}dd}i}i}iiiiii}i}i}iiiiii}di}d}iii}iii}iiiii}d}iiiiiii}dd}iii}iiiii}iiiii}di}d}iiiii}ddi}dddi}di}d}ii}i}}iiii}ii}iiiiii}ddd}i}i}iiiiii}iiiii}iii}iiiii}dd}iiiii}i}iiii}iiii}iiiiii}iiii}iii}ii}iiiii}dd}i}}iii}ii}iii}dd}ii}dd}iiiii}iii}iiii}iiiii}ii}d}iiiiiii}dd}iii}ii}ddi}d}iiiiii}d}i}ii}i}dddi}dd}iiiii}i}i}ddi}ddi}ddd}}iiii}ddd}iiii}iiiii}i}ii}ddd}iiiiii}iiii}iii}iiiii}}iiiii}dd}}iii}dd}ii}iiiii}ii}iii}ii}}iiiiii}i}iiii}iiiii}d}iiii}iiii}iiiiiii}ddd}iii}d}iii}ii}iii}iiiiii}i}i}iiiiii}ii}dd}iiiii}iii}ddd}iiii}iii}ii}iiii}iiiii}iiiiii}iiii}iii}i}iii}ddd}i}iiiii}dddi}ddi}ddi}ddd}ii}iiiiii}}i}i}i}iiii}}i}dddi}d}iii}ii}iiiiii}i}}iiiiiii}dddi}dd}i}i}iiiii}}iii}di}dd}iiiii}dd}i}iii}i}iiii}i}i}iiii}d}iii}dd}ii}iiii}ddd}}i}dd}iiiiii}dd}i}ddd}i}iiiiii}iiiii}i}ddi}di}d}i}iiiiiii}dd}iiiii}d}iiiiii}ii}iiiiiii}ddd}iiiiii}d}iii}ddd}iii}i}dd}i}di}dd}iiiiii}ddd}i}iiiiii}ddd}iiiiii}}iii}i}dd}i}ii}ii}d}iiiii}iiiii}ii}ddd}}}}ii}ii}}iii}i}i}}iiii}iiiii}d}ii}iiiiiii}dd}i}ddi}dd}iiiii}i}dd}iiiiii}iiiii}d}iiiii}dd}ii}iiii}ii}i}i}iiiiiii}di}dd}iiiii}ii}iiii}i}iiiiii}iiiiii}iii}ddd}}i}ddd}iiiiiii}d}iiii}iiii}dd}iii}iii}ii}ddd}iiiiiii}ddi}d}i}iiiii}iiiii}di}ddi}dd}}iiii}dd}ii}iiiiiii}dd}}ii}iiiii}d}ii}d}iiiii}iiiii}ddi}ddd}iiiiiii}dd}}iiiiii}ii}i}ddd}iiiii}iiiiii}do
```

Disclaimer: This crashes TIO. calculates then outputs the number.

## Deadfish / Deadfish~, 6536 bytes

```
iiosdoddddddddoiisiiodddoiiodddoosiiioddddosddodoioddddddooiisdoiodddoioddddodddoiiisodddddooiioododddoosiioiiodddddoiioddosddoddddddoiisodddddddddoiiiodddoiisiioooiiiodododddodsoddodddodosdooddodddosdooioddddddoiioiioddddoddoiisoddddddosodddddddoioiodsodddddddoddoiisoddoiosdoddddddddoiisiiiodddddddoiiisoddddddosddoiioddddddoioiiiodddddddoioisioiiioodddddosdoddddddoosiodddosiiioddddoosdoddodddddoiioioodsdoddoddoddddoiisoioiiiooddddddoiosddoddoddosodddodddddoisiioiioddddddddoiiooioioiioiioddddddddoiisiiodoiiiodddddododoisiiioddddoioddddooiisiiiodddddoisdoddddddddoiioosioddsoddddddosdododddddddoiiisdodddddooiioddsoddddoooddddoiioiooiioododdddoisiiioddddddoiisoddoodddddddoiiioosdoddddddddoiisiiioddoddsoddddddoiioioiiiodddodoiiioddddoiiodddoiiiododdddoisioioiiioddoododdddosiiioddddoiiioddddddoiisoiiioddddosddooddddoiioiiioodddddddoisiioiiiodddddoiiioddddosddoddddoddoiioddoisiiodddoiiioiiioddddddddoiisdooiodddoddddddoiioddoiisiiioiodddddddoisioododooiioioodddddoisiiiodddododddoiisiioiiiooddddododsodddddddoisdoddddddodoiisdoddddoiioddddddoiisiioiioddddoiiioiiodddddddddoiiiosdooddddddoddoiiisoddddddooiooiioiiodddddddoisiiodddosoddddoiiiodddddooiiiodddosdoodoiiodddddddoddoioisiioddddosiiioddddoiiiooiodddddddoiiioosoddddoiiioddddoddoiodddoiisoiioddoddddoiiisodddddddosodddooiosoiioiiiodddddddoisdodddddddoioisdododdoddddoiisodddddddoiodddoiioisooddoiioddddoodoiioddoiioddddoddoiiosioiioiioddddddddoisioiiododddddoioisdoddddoioodddodooiisodddddoddosioiiododdddosiiioiodddddoddoiisdodddddddoisiiododdddodoioiisdoodoioddoddodsdoddoddddoddoiisioddoiiioddoddddoiiiosdodddddoioddoisooddoiioodddddddoiosodddddddddoioisiiodddoosddooddddodddoiisiiioddddoddoiisoddddddododdoiisiiioiioddddoiioodddddddoiisioiiioddddddddoioiosioiiioddddddoisodododdddddoiisdoddddddosiiioiodddddddoiioiiiodddoiioddddodoiisiiiodddddddoiisioododdddoiioodoiisdoodddddoodoisdodddodddoisdooddddoddoisdoddddddosoiooddodddoiiioiiiodddddodoiisiiiodddddddooiiisodddddddddoiiiosdodddodddoisoodddddodddodoiisodsdoddddddddoiisoiiioddddddoiisdoddddddddoooiiisoddoddddosddoiioddodddddoiosoddddddosdododdddddodoioisiiiodoioodoiiodddoiioddddddoisiodoiioiiioddddddoiodsodddddddoisdooodddddddooiiodosiioddddoioddodoiisiiioodddodsoddddodddoisoddddddoiioddddoisodddoiosiioddoiiodoiodddddoioisdodddddddodoiisiioddodsdoioddoddddddoisioioddoooiioiiiodddddddoddoiisoddooioddoioioiioiiodddoddddoiisiiioodoiiododddddddoiisioioddddosodddoisiioddddddooiisoddddoiisiiioiodddooioddooiioiiiodoioooodddddddoioddoiisdoddddddoddoiisiodddosiiioiododddodsoddddddddoiioiiiooiiioddddoioiiioddoiioddodddddddoiiooisoddddddddoiisodddddddddoiisiiodddddoiiosdoddoiiiodddddddddoiisiiodddosoddddddodosiodddosiiiodddddddoiisiiiodddddddoiisoddosiiiodddddosoiioiiodoioddddddosoioddosoddddoiiodddddododoiisiioiiiodddddddoioiioiiioddddddododoiisioddodddoiiiosddoiiodddodddosddodddddoisdodddooddddooiiosoddddooiiioddddddoioiiiodddododoisoddddoiisiiioioddddddddooiisodosdoooddddoiiiodddddodoiisodddooddddddoiisiiioddddoddoisioiioddddoddoisioddddoisiiiodddddoddoiodoiisiiiodddddddoiiosiioiioddoddododdooisiododddoiisdoodddddodddoiioisoddddddddoisiioddoiiioiiododddddddoiioooodddoiisoooddosiioddddddoiisiiiodoiiodddoddsoddoddoodddddoiisiiiodddddosioiiioddddddddoiiosiiioodddddoisoddoiiodddddoddddoiiisdodddddosoddddddddoisiioddoiiioddoddosddoddddoioddoisodddddddoisoddddoiiodddodddodoiisodsdoddddddddoiiisdoddddodsododoiioddoodoiiiodddodddddoisoiiioiioddddododdddooiiisodddddddddoiiisdodddodddddoiisiiioddddoiiiododddoiosddoddddodosiioiioddddddddoiisoddddoiisiiiooddddddoiiodoisodddddddoisoddddddoosodddooddddddoiisoodoiioodddddoiiooisooodddddddoodooisioiiiodddoddddoisiododsoddddddoddoisiiiodddddoisodddddddoiosdoddddodsdoddddoddddoiiisoddodddoddosoddoddoioisioioioddddddoisiiodddoiioddsodddoioddddddoiosiioiiiododddoddsodddddoiodddoddoiiioiiioododoioioiiioddddddosdoddodddddoisoiiiodddodddoisiiioddddddoiisoddodddddoosiiiodddddosodddoisiioiioioddoodoiiodddoiioiiodddoddddddoioiioiiodddoddoiisioddsodddddodsdodddddodddoiisiiiooioddddoiiiodddddddoiisiioiioddddoodsdoodddoioddoiiiodddddoisdodddddosddodddddddoiisiiioiiodoioddddodddoisdoddddddddooiiisdoddddoddddoiisioddddoiioiodsdododdoiioddddddooiiosddodddoiiioioddddoiiiodddddddoiiioioddddoiiisoddddddoddoiodoisiodddddooiisoddddoiiiosoodddddddddoiiisdoddddddoosoioiodddoiiioddddoiooddoisioioiiododdddddoiisdodddddoiiioddoddddoiioisoodddddddddoiiiodoiosddoddddoiioioioddddddodoiiisodddddddosiiiododdddddoiisodooiiioddddodoisiiodddddoiisdoddddddddoiisioiiiodddddoddooisioiiiodddddddoiosodsodddddddddoiisiiiodddodddoiioooiodsdoddddodddoiisdodododdoiioiiiodddoodddosdoddoddddddoiisiiiodddoiooiioddddddoiisdodddddddoioisdoddoddoddddoiisiiioiiodddddodsooddoddddddoisiiododoiodddddoiiodooiosiioioddddddoisiioiiodddddddoisoiododosddoddddosdoddoiiioddoddddoioiiodddddodoiisioddosodddddddoisodddoioiodddddosodddddddddooiisiiioiodddddoiioioiioddddddddoiiiosododddddosdodddddoiodsdododddddosiodddoiosooddddddododdoiisiiooddddddoiisiiooiiiododooddddosoddddddoiiioiiioddddoddosddoddddddoiiododdoiiioodoisododddddodddoiisiioiiodddodddosioiioddddodddoiisioioddoiiioiioddddddoddoiisdodddoioddddosiiioddoddsodddddddddoiiisoddddddddodoiiisdoddoiiioddoiiodddddoodddoisiioiiodddddosodddoddoddddoiiisdodododdddoiodddoiiosioiiioddddddddoioiisodddddddosioddodosiioddddddoiisiioddoiioddddddoiiisoddddddodddoiisoddddoiisiooddddooisioddsodddddodoiiioiiiodddddddosiiioioddddddooddoiisiiiodddddddoiiisodddddddosiiiodddoddddoooiiisdoddddddddoiisiiioddddoddoisiioiiioddddodddosiioiooiiodddddoddooddoiisiiiodddddoisoddddoddoddooiisodddddoioddsododddddddoiisodddddddosiiioddoiiioioddddodddoisdoddddddosioiiiododddddosiiioioddddddoisoddddddddooiioosdoiodddddddoddoiisiiioiiooddddddodosoiiooddddddoiiioiodsododdddodddoiisdoddddddddooiisodddodoiisiioddddddoiisiioddddddooiisioiioiioodddddodddodoiodoiisoddosiiioiioddddddoddoisiioiododddddooiisdodddddoiioioddoddddoiioosiioiooddoodoiiodddddooisiioiiioddddddddoiisoodddoiiodddooiiioddddddoosiodddoioioiiioddddddoisiodddddoiisiioiioddodddddoiisodddoddddosoddoisoddodddddosiioiioddoiiiododdddddddoiisiiioiodddddodosiiioddddddoioiododoisiiiooiiodddddddddoiisoiiioiodoiiodddddddddoiisiiooiiioddddddddoiisdododddddosodsodddddddoisoddddoioiioddddodddoiosiiiododdoddooosiiiodddddosiiioddddddodoiiosiioddddddoiisiiiooiodddoddoioodsdododdddddoisiiioddddddoisiiiodddddddoooiisiiioddoddddodoiiisdooddoodddoiiiodddddoioisdodddoddddoisioddsoddddddddoisiiodddddoiisdodddddddoisiioddddddooiisoddoiosdoddoooddoddddoiioisododdoddddddoiisioiioddddosddoddddddoisoiioiiioddddddddoiisodododdodododddoiisiiioiodddddddoisiiiododdoiodoiododododdoiisiioooddddodoisooddddo
```

Just does the digits.

## Deadfish~, 5965 bytes

```
iiosdo{d}oiisiiodddoiiodddoosiiioddddosddodoio{d}iooiisdoiodddoioddddodddoiiisodddddooiioododddoosiioiiodddddoiioddosddo{d}ioiiso{d}oiiiodddoiisiioooiiiodododddodsoddodddodosdooddodddosdooioddddddoiioiioddddoddoiisoddddddoso{d}iioioiodso{d}iioddoiisoddoiosdo{d}oiisiiio{d}oiiisoddddddosddoiioddddddoioiiio{d}oioisioiiioodddddosdo{d}iioosiodddosiiioddddoosdoddo{d}ioiioioodsdoddoddo{d}oiisoioiiioo{d}iioiosddoddoddosodddo{d}ioisiioiio{d}oiiooioioiioiio{d}oiisiiodoiiiodddddododoisiiioddddoio{d}ooiisiiiodddddoisdo{d}oiioosioddsoddddddosdodo{d}oiiisdodddddooiioddsoddddoooddddoiioiooiioododdddoisiiio{d}ioiisoddoo{d}oiiioosdo{d}oiisiiioddoddsoddddddoiioioiiiodddodoiiioddddoiiodddoiiiododdddoisioioiiioddoododdddosiiioddddoiiio{d}oiisoiiioddddosddooddddoiioiiioo{d}ioisiioiiiodddddoiiioddddosddoddddoddoiioddoisiiodddoiiioiiio{d}ioiisdooiodddo{d}oiioddoiisiiioio{d}ioisioododooiioioo{d}ioisiiiodddododddoiisiioiiiooddddododso{d}iioisdo{d}iiodoiisdoddddoiio{d}oiisiioiioddddoiiioiio{d}oiiiosdoo{d}iioddoiiisoddddddooiooiioiio{d}ioisiiodddosoddddoiiiodddddooiiiodddosdoodoiio{d}iioddoioisiioddddosiiioddddoiiiooio{d}oiiioosoddddoiiioddddoddoiodddoiisoiioddo{d}oiiiso{d}iiosodddooiosoiioiiio{d}iioisdo{d}ioioisdododdoddddoiiso{d}iioiodddoiioisooddoiioddddoodoiioddoiioddddoddoiiosioiioiio{d}ioisioiiodo{d}ioioisdoddddoioodddodooiisodddddoddosioiiododdddosiiioiodddddoddoiisdo{d}ioisiiododdddodoioiisdoodoioddoddodsdoddoddddoddoiisioddoiiioddo{d}oiiiosdodddddoioddoisooddoiioo{d}iioioso{d}oioisiiodddoosddooddddodddoiisiiioddddoddoiisoddddddododdoiisiiioiioddddoiioo{d}oiisioiiio{d}oioiosioiiio{d}iioisododo{d}ioiisdo{d}iiosiiioio{d}ioiioiiiodddoiioddddodoiisiiio{d}oiisioodo{d}oiioodoiisdoodddddoodoisdodddodddoisdooddddoddoisdo{d}iiosoiooddodddoiiioiiio{d}iodoiisiiio{d}ooiiiso{d}oiiiosdodddodddoisoodddddodddodoiisodsdo{d}oiisoiiio{d}ioiisdo{d}oooiiisoddoddddosddoiioddodddddoiosoddddddosdodo{d}iodoioisiiiodoioodoiiodddoiio{d}ioisiodoiioiiioddddddoiodso{d}iioisdooo{d}iooiiodosiioddddoioddodoiisiiioodddodsoddddodddoisoddddddoiioddddoisodddoiosiioddoiiodoio{d}ioioisdo{d}iodoiisiioddodsdoioddo{d}ioisioioddoooiioiiio{d}iioddoiisoddooioddoioioiioiiodddo{d}oiisiiioodoiiodo{d}oiisioioddddosodddoisiio{d}ooiiso{d}oiisiiioiodddooioddooiioiiiodoioooo{d}iioioddoiisdo{d}iioddoiisiodddosiiioiododddodso{d}ioiioiiiooiiioddddoioiiioddoiioddo{d}oiiooiso{d}ioiiso{d}oiisiio{d}ioiiosdoddoiiio{d}oiisiiodddosoddddddodosiodddosiiio{d}oiisiiio{d}oiisoddosiiiodddddosoiioiiodoio{d}iiosoioddosoddddoiiodddddododoiisiioiiio{d}iioioiioiiio{d}iiododoiisioddodddoiiiosddoiiodddodddosddodddddoisdodddooddddooiiosoddddooiiio{d}iioioiiiodddododoiso{d}oiisiiioio{d}ooiisodosdoooddddoiiiodddddodoiisodddoo{d}oiisiiioddddoddoisioiioddddoddoisioddddoisiiiodddddoddoiodoiisiiio{d}oiiosiioiioddoddododdooisiododddoiisdoodddddodddoiioiso{d}ioisiioddoiiioiiodo{d}ioiioooodddoiisoooddosiio{d}oiisiiiodoiiodddoddsoddoddoo{d}oiisiiiodddddosioiiio{d}oiiosiiioodddddoisoddoiiodddddo{d}oiiisdodddddoso{d}ioisiioddoiiioddoddosddoddddoioddoiso{d}iioisoddddoiiodddodddodoiisodsdo{d}oiiisdoddddodsododoiioddoodoiiiodddo{d}ioisoiiioiioddddodo{d}ooiiiso{d}oiiisdodddo{d}oiisiiioddddoiiiododddoiosddoddddodosiioiio{d}oiiso{d}oiisiiioo{d}ioiiodoiso{d}iioisoddddddoosodddoo{d}oiisoodoiioo{d}oiiooisooo{d}iioodooisioiiiodddoddddoisiododsoddddddoddoisiiiodddddoiso{d}iioiosdoddddodsdoddddo{d}oiiisoddodddoddosoddoddoioisioioio{d}ioisiiodddoiioddsodddoio{d}ioiosiioiiiododddoddsodddddoiodddoddoiiioiiioododoioioiiioddddddosdoddo{d}ioisoiiiodddodddoisiiio{d}ioiisoddodddddoosiiiodddddosodddoisiioiioioddoodoiiodddoiioiiodddo{d}oioiioiiodddoddoiisioddsodddddodsdodddddodddoiisiiiooioddddoiiio{d}oiisiioiioddddoodsdoodddoioddoiiiodddddoisdodddddosddo{d}oiisiiioiiodoioddddodddoisdo{d}ooiiisdoddddo{d}oiisioddddoiioiodsdododdoiio{d}iooiiosddodddoiiioioddddoiiio{d}oiiioio{d}oiiisoddddddoddoiodoisio{d}ooiiso{d}oiiiosoo{d}oiiisdo{d}iioosoioiodddoiiioddddoiooddoisioioiiodo{d}ioiisdodddddoiiioddo{d}oiioisoo{d}oiiiodoiosddoddddoiioioio{d}iodoiiiso{d}iiosiiiodo{d}oiisodooiiioddddodoisiio{d}ioiisdo{d}oiisioiiiodddddoddooisioiiio{d}ioiosodso{d}oiisiiiodddodddoiioooiodsdoddddodddoiisdodododdoiioiiiodddoodddosdoddo{d}oiisiiiodddoiooiio{d}ioiisdo{d}ioioisdoddoddo{d}oiisiiioiiodddddodsooddo{d}ioisiiododoio{d}oiiodooiosiioio{d}ioisiioiio{d}ioisoiododosddoddddosdoddoiiioddoddddoioiio{d}iodoiisioddoso{d}iioisodddoioiodddddoso{d}ooiisiiioiodddddoiioioiio{d}oiiiosododddddosdodddddoiodsdododddddosiodddoiosooddddddododdoiisiioo{d}oiisiiooiiiododooddddosoddddddoiiioiiioddddoddosddo{d}ioiiododdoiiioodoisododddddodddoiisiioiiodddodddosioiioddddodddoiisioioddoiiioiioddddddoddoiisdodddoioddddosiiioddoddso{d}oiiiso{d}iodoiiisdoddoiiioddoiiodddddoodddoisiioiiodddddosodddoddo{d}oiiisdodododdddoiodddoiiosioiiio{d}oioiiso{d}iiosioddodosiio{d}oiisiioddoiio{d}oiiisoddddddodddoiiso{d}oiisiooddddooisioddsodddddodoiiioiiio{d}iiosiiioio{d}iiooddoiisiiio{d}oiiiso{d}iiosiiiodddo{d}oooiiisdo{d}oiisiiioddddoddoisiioiiioddddodddosiioiooiiodddddoddooddoiisiiiodddddoisoddddoddoddooiisodddddoioddsodo{d}ioiiso{d}iiosiiioddoiiioioddddodddoisdo{d}iiosioiiiododddddosiiioio{d}iioiso{d}iooiioosdoio{d}iioddoiisiiioiiooddddddodosoiioo{d}oiiioiodsododdddodddoiisdo{d}ooiisodddodoiisiio{d}oiisiio{d}ooiisioiioiioodddddodddodoiodoiisoddosiiioiioddddddoddoisiioiodo{d}iooiisdodddddoiioioddo{d}oiioosiioiooddoodoiio{d}iooisiioiiio{d}ioiisoodddoiiodddooiiio{d}iioosiodddoioioiiio{d}ioisio{d}oiisiioiioddo{d}ioiisodddoddddosoddoisoddodddddosiioiioddoiiiodo{d}oiisiiioiodddddodosiiio{d}ioioiododoisiiiooiio{d}oiisoiiioiodoiio{d}oiisiiooiiio{d}ioiisdododddddosodso{d}iioisoddddoioiioddddodddoiosiiiododdoddooosiiiodddddosiiio{d}iodoiiosiio{d}oiisiiiooiodddoddoioodsdodo{d}ioisiiio{d}ioisiiio{d}oooiisiiioddoddddodoiiisdooddoodddoiiio{d}ioioisdodddoddddoisioddso{d}ioisiio{d}ioiisdo{d}ioisiio{d}ooiisoddoiosdoddoooddo{d}oiioisododdo{d}oiisioiioddddosddo{d}ioisoiioiiio{d}ioiisodododdodododddoiisiiioio{d}ioisiiiododdoiodoiododododdoiisiioooddddodoisoo{d}o
```

Also just does the digits.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 101 bytes

```java
v->{var x=java.math.BigInteger.ZERO;for(int i=280;i>0;)x=x.add(x.valueOf(17<<16).pow(i--));return x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5Ba4QwEIXv/oo5xlLDbg9tIeqhsAs9FKELPbT0kNXojo1JiBPrsvjbbZCeHo/3vZnXy0lmffOz4uCsJ@ij54FQ8zaYmtAafieSWstxhDeJBm4JgAtnjTWMJCnKZLGBIWbsRB5N9/UN0ndjuqEAx/87@Ufk7qtzr2oqoYVinbLyNkkPc7F9HSRd@At2r4ZUpzz/PLxXorWeoSHA4uF5J7DciXQuZi6bhs18kjqoqmX7pzzfP6bc2V@GWZamwisK3sAsllVsK07XkdTAbSDu4kjShrVcOqevzAStYyViS7Ksfw)

### Credits

- fix increasing byte count by 1, and 1 byte reduction by [iota](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99986/iota).

Comment: I believe `x` should start as `BigInteger.ZERO`. [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY5Ba4QwEIXv/oo5xlLDbg9tIeqhsAs9FKELPbT0kNXojo1JiBPrsvjbbZCeHo/3vZnXy0lmffOz4uCsJ@ij54FQ8zaYmtAafieSWstxhDeJBm4JgAtnjTWMJCnKZLGBIWbsRB5N9/UN0ndjuqEAx/87@Ufk7qtzr2oqoYVinbLyNkkPc7F9HSRd@At2r4ZUpzz/PLxXorWeoSHA4uF5J7DciXQuZi6bhs18kjqoqmX7pzzfP6bc2V@GWZamwisK3sAsllVsK07XkdTAbSDu4kjShrVcOqevzAStYyViS7Ksfw)

Comment: @iota Oh yes, I started this believing this would be a multiplication somehow and the ONE stayed there...

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
ṁ`^1114112ḣ280
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxoQ4Q0NDE0NDo4c7FhtZGPz/DwA)

I found out that if you run a Husk program that doesn't take an argument, and include an argument, it errors. [Here's an example](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxoQ4Q0NDE0NDo4c7FhtZGPz//x8A).

### Explanation

```
          ḣ280 # Range from 1 to 280
ṁ              # Map over range and sum...
 `^1114112     # ...114112^n
```

Comment: yep, adding arguments when there is no input causes type inference problems. That is normal.

Comment: @Razetime I found out because I put the result of `ḣ280` in the argument to test it, and instead of removing the argument after I was done, I only cleared it. Then I closed the arguments menu and went back to testing it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
ＩΣＸ⍘!<JOγ…¹¦²⁸¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0VyMgvzy1SMMpsTg1uAQok66hpGjj5a@ko5CuqaMQlJiXnqphqKNgZGGoCQLW////1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    !<JO        Literal string of printable ASCII
   ⍘    γ       Convert from base 95
  Ｘ             Vectorised raise to power
         …¹¦²⁸¹ Range from 1 to 280
 Σ              Take the sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <sup><s>44</s> <s>31</s></sup> 30 bytes

Saved 13 bytes thanks to [Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94066/makonede)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```python
print((x:=17<<16)**281//~-x-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQ6PCytbQ3MbG0ExTS8vIwlBfv063QtdQ8/9/AA)

Comment: [-13](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQ6PCytbQ0NDE0NBIU0vLyMJQX79Ot0LXUPP/fwA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") by using the [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572) and a slight modification on [Deflad0r's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220930/94066).

Comment: @Makonede Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: You can save a byte with `17<<16 == 1114112`

Comment: @ovs Ah, most insightful - thanks! :D

Comment: This has the same length, but is simpler: `print(1114112**281//1114111-1)`.

Comment: @mik Interesting, but I'll stick with what I've got thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
－„｛“ＦＲ］„；＾］∑
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjBEJXUyMDFFJXVGRjVCJXUyMDFDJXVGRjI2JXVGRjMyJXVGRjNEJXUyMDFFJXVGRjFCJXVGRjNFJXVGRjNEJXUyMjEx,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 33 bytes

```perl
say+(($q=1114112)**281-$q)/($q-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbQ0Ol0NbQ0NDE0NBIU0vLyMJQV6VQUx8oqmuo@f//v/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBkA6KTM9M68EAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 14 bytes

```
#280;1114112^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X9nIwsDa0NDQxNDQKE7l/38A)

### Explanation

```
#280            n = 280
    ;           output sum of first n terms
     1114112^$  each term is 1114112 ^ current index
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbigint`, 26 bytes

```perl
say 1114112**281/1114111-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLB0NDQxNDQSEvLyMJQH8Ix1DX8//9ffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0MDIJ2UmZ6ZVwIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 30 bytes

```perl6
say 1114112**281 div 1114111-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVLB0NDQxNDQSEvLyMJQISWzDCpgqGv4/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
print 1114112**281/1114111-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwdDQ0MTQ0EhLy8jCUB/CMdQ1/P8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>39</s> 36 bytes

Based on the formula presented in [@Delfad0r's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220942/80745).

```powershell
[bigint]::Pow(1114112,281)/1114111-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/PzopMz0zryTWyiogv1zD0NDQxNDQSMfIwlBTH8Ix1DX8/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 60 bytes

```fs
printf"%A"(Seq.sumBy(fun i->bigint.Pow(1114112I,i)){1..280})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/v6AoM68kTUnVUUkjOLVQr7g016lSI600TyFT1y4pMx0oqReQX65haGhoYmho5KmTqalZbainZ2RhUKv5/z8A)